# Why is Excel autosaving but not saving my file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010, autosave

My file is being autosaved by Excel (Office Professional Plus 2010).  However, if I perform the `Save` operation (Ctrl-S) nothing is being saved.

Comment: If already autosaved then it wouldn't need to save it again.

Comment: I don't need to save again. But I want to be able to save at a specific point in time that I can go back to.

Comment: But if there's no change since the last autosave?... I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Autosave is on a schedule. It happens regardless of what has changed or not changed in the file. Having the capability to save on demand allows the establishment of a 'checkpoint' with the file in a specific known state, usually prior to one or more autosaves.

Comment: This isn't the same as the system restore points. Office amd other software typically only actually save on demand if there are changes since the last saved version.

Comment: Where did you save the Workbook? Local or online?

Comment: Both 'AutoRecover file location' and 'Default file location' are on a network drive.NONE of my ,xlsb files have ever been saved other than by autorecover in spite of my attempts to save them manually.